# how to resolve spray.json.package when trying spray json?

Tags: scala, maven, akka, spray

I have this maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.spray</groupId>
        <artifactId>spray-json_${scala.majorversion}</artifactId>
        <version>${spray-json.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <scala.majorversion>2.10</scala.majorversion>
    <scala.version>${scala.majorversion}.2</scala.version>
    <akka.version>2.2.0</akka.version>
    <spray.version>1.2-M8</spray.version>
    <spray-json.version>1.2.5</spray-json.version>
```

however i get this from spray json:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spray.json.package$
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified the `dependency` `scope` as `provided`.  This means you will make available this dependency yourself.  If this is not what you intended, you may want to change the `scope` suitably.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide it in your example, but spray has it's own repo, did you manage to add it?

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spray</id>
      <url>http://repo.spray.io/</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>
```